# WSO2 ESB - Configuring Amazon SQS as a Message Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, wso2, amazon-sqs, wso2-esb

Is there a possibility to configure **Amazon SQS** as a **Message Store** in WSO2 ESB ? Using a **Custom Message Store** ?

I don't simply want to configure a **SQS Connector** but **a fully integrated SQS Message Store** able to be used by a **Message Processor**. If not, how can I consume my SQS Store on the ESB ? Can I have to write a **Custom Message Processor** which retrieve messages from the SQS Queue using the SQS Connector ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Just connect to the SQS api and call `receiveMessage()`. That's it.

Comment: I need more details about ESB (and, why not, Message Broker) configuration in order to pub/sub messages in a SQS Queue.